# searching for a keyword in db in my iphone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, nspredicate

I want to know how can i implement keyword searching in my app. Actually i want to enter a text (in  `uitextfield` ), then search my sqlite db and find out corresponding text in db.Iam a new bee to iPhone development, waiting for your help. Remember, i want to search in multiple tables.
                                      Thanks in advance...

Comment: And looking at you `xcode` tag it shows that you are indeed a new bee

Comment: @InderKumarRathore: u r right 'm really a new guy to iphone dev. and now on the move to make an app. I already have some  tables there in sqlite3 and want to search in these tables for specific text.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore: actually 'm asking first time here in stackoverflow, and i was not aware of the 'tag' function at that time.. nw i got what is 'tag'.thnx.

Answer (score 0):

First populate your array from DB which you might have done.

Use NSPredicate for filtering, because fetching records from DB includes memory usage.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText];
arrSearch  = [[arrOriginal filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: thanx for the response, i have multiple tables and i want to look at these tables for the entered searching text.Could u please provide me a more precise example, remember; 'm a new bee..

Comment: are u using tables with searchbar

Comment: i already do have a filtering uisearch bar there in my view, i need another 'searching mechanism' to go through out my database. I dont know what control  should i use for this.

Comment: @RahulGupta ur right. First take all records from DB in an array & then apply the predicate for searching.